# Display a simple alert dialog in Material Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I'm using Material Angular (from [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/)). The examples in the site seem a Little too overcomplicated and every other tutorial in the internet seems either outdated or to be using AngularJS instead. How can I show a simple alert (just like Android's AlertDialog) with a title, a message and a confirm/cancel button?

Comment: Here is a very good example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/dnbaljqbqpea?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**EDIT**:

You could also use a template reference in your component's HTML file (or more commonly known as a "component view") and then reference it in your component's TypeScript file and then pass that reference to `MatDialog#open`.

Alternatively, you can access a reference of the template in your component's view and then pass it to a method you defined that accepts the reference.

If you're confused with what I just typed out, check out the code below (the first dialog demonstrates the first sentence and the second dialog showcases what I explained in the second sentence)

(Assuming the following structure once again)

```
app/
  app.component.html
  app.component.ts
```

`app.component.html`:

```html
<button mat-button (click)="openDialogWithRef(firstDialog)">Open dialog with reference</button>
<button mat-button (click)="openOtherDialog()">Open dialog in code</button>

<ng-template #firstDialog>
  <h2 matDialogTitle>Hello, world!</h2>
  <p matDialogContent><em>Content for this dialog goes here...</em></p>
  <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button mat-button matDialogClose>Dismiss</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #secondDialog>
  <h2 matDialogTitle>Hello, second dialog!</h2>
  <p matDialogContent>Interesting note: This template reference was referenced in code with the <code>@ViewChild</code>, which lets you query components/template references in the component view.</p>
  <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button mat-button matDialogClose>Dismiss</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
```

`app.component.ts` (shortened):

```
import { ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

// ...
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('secondDialog') secondDialog: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openDialogWithRef(ref: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.dialog.open(ref);
  }

  openOtherDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(this.secondDialog);
  }
}
```

This method can save you some hassle in creating new components just for dialogs, as well as declaring them in your module's `entryComponents`.

However, this can quickly become troublesome if you have multiple dialog templates in a single component view.

---

**Original answer**

Here's a simple example as you requested:

(Assuming the following structure)

```
app/
  my-alert-dialog/
    my-alert-dialog.component.html
    my-alert-dialog.component.ts
  app.component.ts
  app.module.ts
```

`my-alert-dialog.component.html`

```html
<h2 matDialogTitle>Unregister?</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <p>When you unregister, all your data will be removed. Continue?</p>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <!--
    Note that you can pass in anything to the `matDialogClose` attribute. This also includes objects, arrays, etc.
    Just make sure that you make it a property binding with those [] brackets
    Example: <button mat-button [matDialogClose]="{'lol': true}">Cancel</button>
  -->
  <button mat-button matDialogClose="cancel" color="primary">Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button matDialogClose="confirm" color="warn">Unregister</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Explanation of the above code:

- `[matDialogTitle]` / `[mat-dialog-title]`: A directive (typically used on a `h2` element) for indicating the dialog's title.
- `[matDialogContent]` / `[mat-dialog-content]` / `mat-dialog-content`: A directive indicating the dialog's content.
- `[matDialogActions]` / `[mat-dialog-actions]` / `mat-dialog-actions`: A directive indicating the dialog's action(s).
- `[matDialogClose]` / `[mat-dialog-close]`: A directive (typically used on a `button` element) indicating that this element when clicked on should close the dialog. Optionally, this directive can include a parameter (of `any` type) which can be then passed to the component who opened this dialog.

`my-alert-dialog.component.ts`

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-alert-dialog', // Replace with your own selector
  templateUrl: './my-alert-dialog.component.html'
})
export class MyAlertDialogComponent { }
```

`app.component.ts` (redacted)

```ts
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { MyAlertDialogComponent } from './my-alert-dialog/my-alert-dialog.component';
// ...
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }
  unregister() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyAlertDialogComponent);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      // NOTE: The result can also be nothing if the user presses the `esc` key or clicks outside the dialog
      if (result == 'confirm') {
        console.log('Unregistered');
      }
    })
  }
}
```

`app.module.ts` (redacted)

```ts
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MyAlertDialogComponent } from './my-alert-dialog/my-alert-dialog.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
    MyAlertDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    // ...
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    // See https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#configuring-dialog-content-via-code-entrycomponents-code- for more info
    MyAlertDialogComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-dialog-so)

Comment: Is there any one line way I don't need to create a component and use a default template?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen AFAIK, it's currently not possible.

Comment: @QianChen You could use a template reference to a template that exists in the same component HTML file and then get that reference and pass it to `MatDialog#open`.

Comment: Hi, @Edric. I am trying to play with your code, but how can you pass HTML object to `dialogMsg`? I can only pass a string to the body.

Comment: @user3622260 You could either pass in HTML as a string and then sanitise it in the dialog's code, or pass in a sanitised version of the HTML you're trying to set.

Comment: Ah yes, angular, the framework that converts even the most simple thing into 15 files and 300 lines of code.

Answer (score 6):

I had used a sweet Alert.  https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-sweetalert2-tutorial/#.X2nNxmgzZPY

It´s the most easy and fast method to create alerts in angular.

```
$ npm install --save sweetalert2
```

Use `import Swal from 'sweetalert2';` in your TS file together with the Alert `Swal.fire('This is a simple and sweet alert')`

Comment: I tried all answers, and this is a much better thing because it is easier and more customizable, anyone reading should use this.

Answer (score 1):

Install `npm i @angular/material`, add `component` for `dialog`, example `EmployeeDialog`.

Suppose you want `table` in dialog also `close button` on top right.

`EmployeeDialog.html` file code

```
<div md-dialog-content>
<!-- This button to close dialog -->
<button class="close" mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">
 <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
 
</button>   
<div>   
 <table>
   <th>Id</th><th>Name</th>Addess<th></th><
   <tr *ngFor="let emp of emplyee; let i = index" border="1">
     <td>{{emp.DeviceID}}</td>
     <td>{{emp.FriendlyName}}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>   
</div>   
</div>
```

Your `EmployeeDialog.ts` file should be

```
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
export class EmployeeDialog implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EmployeeDialog>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any){ }
  
  //write code to handle close
  }
}
```

Now if you want to open `EmployeeDialog` from `SourceComponent`, whenever `Employeelist()` function call you `diaglog` will open

`SourceComponent.ts` file

```
public Employeelist()
{
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EmployeeDialog, {
    width: '80%',
    height:'80%',
    panelClass: 'my-dialog',
    disableClose: true ,
    data: employeeList
  });
}
```

code in `app.module.ts` file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmployeeDialog,
    SourceComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [EmployeeDialog],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```