# call material dialog as alert from service.ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, material-design, angular-material, angular2-services

I am using **angular material**. I am handling common error response in the handleError method in my **service.ts** file. I want to popup material dialog when I get an error instead of alert from **service.ts** file.

How can I implement this?

I am new to the angular material.

**Code:**

```
export class CommonService {
  public api = 'https://URl'
  public showSpinner: boolean = false;
  public auth: boolean = false;
  public fetch: boolean = false;

  constructor(public http: Http) { }

  postCall() {
    this.showSpinner = false;
    this.auth = false;
    this.fetch = false;

    var header = {
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      }, "grant_type": "password",
      "scope": "user",
      "client_id": "4874eafd0f7a240625e59b2b123a142a669923d5b0d31ae8743f6780a95187f5",
      "client_secret": "908f6aee4d4cb27782ba55ae0c814bf43419f3220d696206212a29fe3a05cd88",
      "auth_token": "azd4jXWWLagyb9KzgfDJ"
    };
    return this.http.post(this.api + '/oauth/token.json', header)
      .map(response => {
        this.showSpinner = true;
        this.auth = true;
        this.fetch = false;

        setTimeout(function () {
          let result = response.json();
          window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', result.access_token);
        }, 4000);

        return true;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError)
  }


  getCaseStudy() {
    this.showSpinner = true;
    this.auth = false;
    this.fetch = true;

    let headers = new Headers();
    let token = window.localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');

    let Hdata = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers })

    return this.http.get(this.api + '/upend URl', Hdata)
      .map(response => {
        this.showSpinner = false;
        this.fetch = false;
        this.auth = false;
        return response.json()
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError() {
    return Observable.throw(
      alert('problem somewhere')
    )
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its an access token error. please recheck your header params again.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49472031/display-a-simple-alert-dialog-in-material-angular

Comment: yes, I had checked they invoke dialog on button click from the same component I want to display or popup dialog from service.ts file

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component `ErrorDialog` that would be at root level. In `AppComponent` subscribe a subject declared in `CommonService` that will provide boolean value.

In `CommonService` you can do this as:

```
private subject = new Subject<any>();

updateDialog(isVisible: boolean) {
    this.subject.next({ isVisible: isVisible });
}

getDialogVisibility(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
}

handleError(error: any) {
    ...
    this.updateDialog(true);
    ...
}
```

In your component subscribe `getDialogVisibility` and whenever value is being changed from service you can get to know if dialog should be displayed.

**AppComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:`
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <error-dialog></error-dialog>
    `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
    subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {
        this.subscription = this.commonService.getDialogVisibility().subscribe(isVisible => { 
            if(isVisible) {
                openErrorDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    openErrorDialog() {
        // write your code
    }
}
```

Comment: what about ErrorDialog compoent where i should call it

Comment: in template of app component, you can add it as <error-dialog></error-dialog>